# get specific data from the variable php

Tags: php

```
$vari="Love is an emotion of a strong <"/affection and personal/"> attachment. Love is also a virtue representing <"/all of human kindness/">, compassion, and affection";
```

looking for output which is starts from <"/ and ends with /">.

output:

```
affection and personal
all of human kindness
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: Those quotes need to be escaped for it to be a valid line. (Or enclose the whole thing in single quotes instead of double.) As is, it would throw an error. I guess you just mean to show what the contents of `$vari` is, and that's not a line of actual code?

Answer (score 1):

```
$vari='Love is an emotion of a strong <"/affection and personal/"> attachment. '
   . 'Love is also a virtue representing <"/all of human kindness/">, '
   . ' compassion, and affection';
preg_match_all('@<"/(.*?)/">@', $vari, $matches);
var_dump($matches[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the entire thing is a properly escaped string, you can use this function to get an array of all the portions

```
<?php

function cutMultiple($start, $end, $from)
{
    $results = array(); // init the output
    $step1 = explode($start, $from);    // get the results

    for( $i = 1; $i<count($step1); $i++)
    {
        $outputs = explode($end, $step1[$i]);   // get final cut
        $results[] = $outputs[0];   // append the cut
    }

    return $results;
}

$text = 'Love is an emotion of a strong <"/affection and personal/"> attachment. Love is also a virtue representing <"/all of human kindness/">, compassion, and affection';

echo cutMultiple('<"/', '/">', $text);

?>
```

Or go with the regex approach.

I must say that this isn't the best solution to the problem, but definitely a quick one